# Why doesn't MYSQL stored procedure call work from my code

Tags: php, mysql, stored-procedures

I have a MYSQL stored procedure, It results like this- when I run it in my MYSQL workbench query browser:

```
CALL Dummy_2('table_105', '0000-00-00 00:00:00', '2014-09-19 05:38:51')

35 row(s) returned  0.531 sec / 0.000 sec
```

But when i call it from my code it does not make any change to the table, here is the code that i use from my php script:

```
$query = ("CALL Dummy_2($table, $old_date, $new_date)");
$excute = mysql_query($query);
```

Comment: try to add/wrap quotations inside it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quote procedure params

```
$query = ("CALL Dummy_2('{$table}', '{$old_date}', '{$new_date}')");
$excute = mysql_query($query);
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if the variables contain proper values before use them. And if so, try running this :

```
$query = ("CALL Dummy_2('$table', '$old_date', '$new_date')");
$excute = mysql_query($query);
```